# Iterate through each of the values in one SQL table to find the associated records in another table

Tags: sql, cursor

In SQL, I need to return a set of records from one table based on each value of a field in a Lookup table.  So I have a lookup table that contains a filename field and I need to iterate through each of the filenames and find the records in another table based on this field (filename is the keyfield in both tables). After I identify each set of records, I need to then save each of them as a CSV file locally on my computer. I tried the below cursor and it's not working. Can someone assist?

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path to save file
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for output file DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

SET @path = 'C:\Output\'

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT * FROM dbo.filenamelookup fl JOIN dbo.recordstable rt ON fl.filename = rt.filename OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO #temp

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.csv'
BACKUP DATABASE #temp TO DISK = @fileName

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers but I don't think I did a good job at explaining my question so let me try again. There are two tables, one is a lookup table that contains filenames and the other table contains all the records associated to each of the filenames. I need to export all the filenames from the lookup table *and* their associated records from the other table. So there should be multiple files produced from this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MSSQL, I would say use the BCP or SQLCMD utilities.  Here is a previous post on the same issue:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file